# How do I get Replace to work with a complex repeating pattern?

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching

I'm new to Mathematica, but with extensive searching and a lot of experimenting I can't seem to get this to work.

I have a list of strings of the form:

```
list = { "*A", "B", "*C", "D" , "E", "F", "*G", "H", "*I"};
```

The elements starting with `*` can be followed by zero or more elements that don't start with `*`. I am trying to use pattern matching to construct a function that would for example take `f["*C"]` and return `{ "D", "E", "F" }`.

I've been trying:

```
Replace[list, { ___, "*C", 
   r : Repeated[ y_ /; ! hasStarQ[y]], ___} -> { "*C", r} ]
```

Where `hasStarQ` checks if the string starts with `*`. This almost produces the right result:

```
{"*C", "D"}
```

But I can't get it to match `"D", "E", "F"`. Similar results for:

```
SequenceCases[list, {"*C", Longest[Repeated[ y_ /; ! hasStarQ[y]]]} ]
```

and

```
SequenceReplace[list, {___, "*C", 
   r : Longest[Repeated[ y_ /; ! hasStarQ[y]]], Shortest@___} :> r]
```

I recognise that I can achieve what I need using `SplitBy` but I wonder whether there is a more elegant way to achieve this goal!

Comment: `SequenceCases[list, {"*C",  x__?(NoneTrue[{##}, StringStartsQ["*"]] &)} :> {x}]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SequenceCases[list, 
    {"*C", x__} /;  Nor @@ StringStartsQ[{x}, "*"] :> {x}]
```

> ```
> {{"D", "E", "F"}}
> ```

```
Cases[{"*C", x___} :> {x}]@Split[list, Not@StringStartsQ["*"]@#2 &]
```

> ```
> {{"D", "E", "F"}}
> ```

Comment: Many thanks. So the trick is to test the whole results list rather than the individual elements.

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {"*A", "B", "*C", "D", "E", "F", "*G", "H", "*I"};
```

Build and query an `Association`

```
look =
 GroupBy[#, First -> Rest, First]& @ Split[list, !StringStartsQ[#2, "*"] &]
```

<|"*A" -> {"B"}, "*C" -> {"D", "E", "F"}, "*G" -> {"H"}, "*I" -> {}|>

```
look["*C"]
```

{"D", "E", "F"}

```
Lookup[look, {"*A", "*C", "*X"}, {}]
```

{{"B"}, {"D", "E", "F"}, {}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {"*A", "B", "*C", "D", "E", "F", "*G", "H", "*I"};
```

Using `SequenceSplit`:

```
rep = {__, "*C", x__} /; Nor @@ StringStartsQ[{x}, "*"] :> {x};

Select[SequenceSplit[list, rep], ContainsOnly[StringFreeQ[#, "*"], {True}] &]

(*{{"D", "E", "F"}}*)
```

Or using `SequenceReplace`:

```
Cases[{__}]@SequenceReplace[list, rep]

(*{{"D", "E", "F"}}*)
```